# HTML structure - fill space between 2 floated divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a layout where I have left and right floated columns with some content inbetween, filling all available space. What markup/CSS can I use to achieve the following? My content div is always incorrectly wrapping the right floated div below it.

Fiddle of what I'm trying: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj35q851/)

```
<div style="float: left;">
    left floated content
</div>

<div>
    fill space between left and right floated content
</div>

<div style="float: right;">
    right floated content
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use an HTML `table` with three columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it if those floated divs are fixed width.

```
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid blue; width: 150px;">
    left floated content
</div>

<div style="float: right; border: 1px solid green; width:150px;">
    right floated content
</div>

<div style="margin-right:150px; margin-left:150px;">
    fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is wrap your `divs` into a parent with `display: flex`.

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 10px;">
    left floated content
  </div>

  <div>
    fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content fill
    space between left and right floated content fill space between left and right floated content
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; border: 1px solid green; margin-left: 10px;">
    right floated content
  </div>
</div>
```